# ¿Cómo superpongo más de dos imágenes?

Tags: java

Estoy elaborando un software para un consultorio odontológico, y para registrar la evolución del paciente
utilizo tanto el odontograma inicial como el odontograma que registra los procedimientos hechos al paciente.

Para ello utilizo las imágenes de cada uno de los dientes (en lugar de imágenes rectangulares).

Muestro cada imagen como un icon de cada jLabel.

Ya que sobre cada diente se superpondrá una figura (ej.: se marca una X como ausente, etc)

¿cómo superpongo más de dos imágenes?

Comment: bienvenido quizas quieras leer esto -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour por otro lado quizas puedas dividir la pregunta formulando dos o varias preguntas no todas juntas, porque por un lado te sera mas facil poner un titulo descriptivo y no el que tiene, y por otro quizas alguien te pueda responder a una pregunta pero no a las otras, y al tener un titulo mas descriptivo podra ser util para futuros usuarios. Saludos

Comment: podria dejar el punto 1 y borrar hacia abajo y con eso formular la segunda   pregunta si quieres. Saludos

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por su objeción.

Comment: Entiendo que tienes una imagen sólida que es el odontograma vacío. Y varias imágenes que son transparentes y que tienen varias figuras que quieres superponer sobre la imagen principal. Y que todas las imágenes tienen el mismo tamaño. ¿Es así? ¿Admites el uso de alguna librería externa como opencv?

Comment: Es así, la verdad que no uso ninguna librería. Cree usted que están bien las imágenes en un JLabel ? Recordando que el lenguaje que uso es java. Ya que además de superponer imágenes debo pintar también dichas imágenes.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Opencv es una librería para procesamiento de imágenes para tareas altamente especializadas como reconocer rostros humanos desde una fuente de video en tiempo real, sería como matar una mosca con un cañón, además de que el exceso de código no utilizado, es decir inútil, perjudica a las aplicaciones hechas en Java.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo que se conoce en [java](/questions/tagged/java) como un [javabean](/questions/tagged/javabean), aplicando el patrón de diseño [bean](/questions/tagged/bean) específico para interfaces gráficas, que no es otra cosa que aplicar completamente la encapsulación y dejar un constructor sin argumentos. Para hacerlo deberás implementar el patrón de diseño Vista/Controlador mejor conocido como [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc). La manipulación de imágenes se logra mediante [java-awt](/questions/tagged/java-awt) según el estado, y simplemente procedes a llamar al método `setIcon`.

[image: Superposición de dos imágenes]

### Código de Ejemplo

Botón:

```
package dientesjava;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import static java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 *
 * @author Javatlacati
 */
public class BotonDiente extends JButton {

    public final static int NORMAL = 0;
    public final static int AUSENTE = 1;
    /**
     * imagen base
     */
    public final static String IMG_NORMAL = "8gj9z3ln.png";
    public final static String IMG_AUSENTE = "xe1aas2d.png";
    private static final int NUMERO_DE_ESTADOS = 2;
    private static final String RUTA_BASE = "/dientesjava/";
    private int estadoDelDiente = NORMAL;

    public BotonDiente() {
        initComponents();
        dibujarIcono();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        cambiarEstado();
        dibujarIcono();
    }                                 

    public void cambiarEstado() {
        if (estadoDelDiente < NUMERO_DE_ESTADOS - 1) {
            estadoDelDiente++;
        } else {
            estadoDelDiente = NORMAL;
        }
    }

    public int getEstadoDelDiente() {
        return estadoDelDiente;
    }

    public void setEstadoDelDiente(int estadoDelDiente) {
        this.estadoDelDiente = estadoDelDiente;
    }

    private void dibujarIcono() {
        final Class clase = getClass();
        final URL normal = clase.getResource(RUTA_BASE + IMG_NORMAL);
        final URL faltante = clase.getResource(RUTA_BASE + IMG_AUSENTE);
        final ImageIcon iconoDienteNormal = new ImageIcon(normal);
        final ImageIcon iconoDienteFaltante = new ImageIcon(faltante);
        final Image image1 = iconoDienteNormal.getImage();
        final Image image2 = iconoDienteFaltante.getImage();
        //int w = image1.getWidth( puede ir tambien el tamaño de la imagen si lo conoces );
        //int h = image1.getHeight(puede ir tambien el tamaño de la imagen si lo conoces);
        final int ancho = this.getPreferredSize().width;
        final int alto = this.getPreferredSize().height;
        final Image image = new BufferedImage(ancho, alto, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics2D graficos2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        graficos2D.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
        graficos2D.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, null);
        graficos2D.dispose();

        final ImageIcon newImg = new ImageIcon(image);
        switch (estadoDelDiente) {
            case AUSENTE:
                setIcon(newImg);
                break;
            //otros casos como diente picado en alguna parte
            default: //incluye NORMAL
                setIcon(iconoDienteNormal);
                break;
        }
    }                  
}
```

Formulario:

```
package dientesjava;

/**
 *
 * @author Javatlacati
 */
public class PanelDentadura extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PanelDentadura() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        botonDiente1 = new dientesjava.BotonDiente();
        botonDiente2 = new dientesjava.BotonDiente();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));
        getContentPane().add(botonDiente1);
        getContentPane().add(botonDiente2);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelDentadura.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelDentadura.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelDentadura.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PanelDentadura.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PanelDentadura().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private dientesjava.BotonDiente botonDiente1;
    private dientesjava.BotonDiente botonDiente2;

}
```

### Ventajas de este enfoque

Espero este código te pueda ser de utilidad, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero esta es mi favorita, debido a que puedes hacerlo en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) mediante el tipo `FormularioBean` del tipo `Formularios de interfaz gráfica`, y después agregarlo a la `paleta de componentes` si deseas reusarlo en muchos proyectos mediante arrastrar y soltar la clase de la `vista de Proyectos` a la paleta, o arrastrando y soltando la clase a un formulario abierto desde la `vista de Proyectos`.